# Variable value set in Controller. How to get that in XAML.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, xaml, global-variables

I have an MVC4 application.  While getting the database response, I'm assigning a particular value from that response to a static variable (which is declared in "namespace A").  Set it happening fine in namespace B.  But while trying to retrieve that value in XAML.cs (say namespace C), it is always returning 0.
All 3 are running under the same app pool on the server.
I understand that the controller can always pass values to a View, from there to Silverlight.  Since, it's just a single value ("long" type), I would like to explore is there a way like global variable whose value is set at Controller level and read in XAML.cs

**My CSHTML code:**

```
<object id="slvObject" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="800px"> 
        @{                     
            string sourceValue = @"/../../*.xap";                   
            string xappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"") + @"\" + sourceValue;
            DateTime xapCreationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(xappath);
            sourceValue = sourceValue + "?ignore=" + xapCreationDate.ToString();                             
        }
        <param name="source" value="~/../../*.xap" />
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="windowless" value="true"/>
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.60818.0" />
        <param name="initParams" value="@DataKeyNameConstants.val1=@val1,@DataKeyNameConstants.val2=@val2"/>
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.60818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
        </a>
```

I have my app.xaml.cs from where my Mainpage.xaml.cs constructor is called.  From the constructor, I have a call method1()

**XAML.cs:**

```
private void method1()
        {
            string str = GetApplicationAbsoluteURL() + "/MyController/GetValue?val1=" + _val1.ToString() + "&val2=" + _val2.ToString();
            MyHelper.ReadDataAsynchronously(str, CompleteTask);
        }
```

**Controller**

```
public string GetValue(int val1, int val2)
{
    GetValueResponse _valueResponse = _serviceClient.GetValue(val1, val2);
//In this _valueResponse, I get a value Id "_valueResponse.Id" which is of long type.  I would like that value to be sent to XAML.cs (May be if it can be stored in a global variable and used there)
    return _valueResponse.XMLValue; 
}
```

Then the control comes to my XAML.cs file's **CompleteTask** method:

```
private void CompleteTask(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//Here is where I would like to read the value and it comes "0" all the time
}
```

Also one additional thing I would like to ask.  If we could achieve this by some means, would this value always be refreshed on every assignment of the long variable? (i.e. The reason for my question is, since .xap file is pre-compiled, I don't want it to record the value once and use it all the time.  I would like this to re-load every time I call the page as the value might come different).

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the XAP file runs in the browser, so it is located in a completely different domain than your server-side code (controller, etc).

The way to do this, assuming you only need the value loaded once per page load, is to set its value server-side using `initParams`.  Just extend what you're already doing -- add "val3" to `DataKeyNameConstants`, set `@val3 = your constant`, and use:

```
<param name="initParams" value="@DataKeyNameConstants.val1=@val1,@DataKeyNameConstants.val2=@val2,@DataKeyNameConstants.val3=@val3"/>
```

Then, in the Silverlight code, [retrieve the value `Application_Startup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.startupeventargs.initparams%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MyConstants.MyConstant = e.InitParams["MyConstantKey"];
}
```

Now you've got it available in a static variable (`MyConstants` or whatever) within the Silverlight app.